# How to print a four character hexadecimal in C?

Tags: c

```
for (int x= 7; 0<=x; x--) {
        size_t x_val = ((1<<4)-1) & io>>x*4;
        printf("%lX", x_val);
```

Trying to print a hexadecimal number here after converting it from integer. While the conversion is successful, the output is `FFFFFFCD` instead of the desired output `FFCD`. How can I limit maximum 4 characters to be printed?

Comment: Use `%04X`, not `%lX`.

Comment: You could mask off the upper portion in the `printf`: `x_val & 0xffff`

Comment: Actually, @Barmar, since `x_val` is a `size_t`, it should be `%04zX`. Also, @PratikS, where is `io` defined?

Comment: `signed int io; fscanf(fp, "%d", &io);` @SGeorgiades it is a given code

Comment: @sj95126 `printf("%lX", x_val & 0xffff);` is what I used. It still gives me the same output.

Comment: The `%*x` format is a *minimum* width not a restriction, and allows it to overflow so the true number takes priority over the width. The `size_t` is unsigned, to crop the leading digits you can `& 0xFFFF`.

Comment: `for (int x= 7; 0<=x; x--)` --> `for (int x= 3; 0<=x; x--)`.

Comment: @PratikS What is the value and type of `io` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> to print a four character hexadecimal

1. Limit value to the [0...0xFFFF] range.
2. Print 4 digits padded with zeros with the correct specifier.

Example

```
unsigned masked_value = io & 0xFFFF;
printf("%04X\n", masked_value);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one,

You can use `hh` to tell printf that the argument is an `unsigned char`. Use `0` to get zero padding and `4` to set the width to `4`. `x` or `X` for lower/uppercase `hex` characters.

```
uint8_t a = 0x0a;
printf("%02hhX", a); // Prints "0A"
printf("0x%02hhx", a);
```

Comment: Can you show me how to do that in context of my code? I have tried this previously but doesn't seem to work.

Comment: your description is for 4 character.  the code demonstrates only 2 character.

Comment: The width spec sets a *minimum* width, to which the value is padded, not a maximum.